# Android customize the look of FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment`-based app with a subclass of `FragmentPagerAdapter` managing the Fragments. I would like to set custom images for tabs in the PagerAdapter, but don't see any methods for doing this in the API. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the best practices of "Material Design", on tab layout the **pattern is text or image/text.**
But if you really want do this:

On **/res/layout** create your **custom_layout.xml**

On your **CustomFragmentPagerAdapter** create your **view**

```
 public View getTabView(int position) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);

    ImageView imgTabIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgTabIcon);
    TextView tvTabTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTabTitle);
    TextView tvTabAmount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTabAmount);

    imgTabIcon.setImageResource(imageResId[position]);
    tvTabTitle.setText(tabTitles[position]);
return v;
```

On your **Fragment**

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_custom_tabs, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    CustomFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new CustomFragmentPagerAdapter(
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), getActivity());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }
return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tabs in `FragmentPagerAdapter` like this:

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("your_fragment_tag").setIndicator("Tab Text", 
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon)),
            YourFragment.class, null);
```

Comment: I have the same problem but this reply shows too little code to understand. In what method should I put that code? How do I get mTabsAdapter and mTabHost instances?